# Java 8 groupingby Into map that contains a list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following data:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> products = new ArrayList<>();

Map<String, Object> product1 = new HashMap<>();
product1.put("Id", 1);
product1.put("number", "123");
product1.put("location", "ny");

Map<String, Object> product2 = new HashMap<>();
product2.put("Id", 1);
product2.put("number", "456");
product2.put("location", "ny");

Map<String, Object> product3 = new HashMap<>();
product3.put("Id", 2);
product3.put("number", "789");
product3.put("location", "ny");

products.add(product1);
products.add(product2);
products.add(product3);
```

I'm trying to stream over the products list, group by the id and for each id have a list on number, while returning a Map that contains three keys: Id, List of number, and a location.

So my output would be:

```
List<Map<String, Object>>> groupedProducts
map[0]
    {id:1, number[123,456], location:ny}
map[1]
    {id:2, number[789], location:ny}
```

I have tried:

```
Map<String, List<Object>> groupedProducts = products.stream()
      .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
      .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getKey, mapping(Entry::getValue, toList())));
```

which prints:

```
{number=[123, 456, 789], location=[ny, ny, ny], Id=[1, 1, 2]}
```

I realise `Map<String, List<Object>>` is incorrect, but it's the best I could achieve to get the stream to work.  Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: What should happen if two maps have the same ID but different locations? For example, if there was a 4th map `{Id:2, number:101, location:ma}`.

Comment: In this scenario the third key will always be the same ...Its just there to show the map will have three keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case grouping by `Id` key with [`Collectors.collectingAndThen(downstream, finisher)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) could do the trick. Consider following example:

```
Collection<Map<String, Object>> finalMaps = products.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(it -> it.get("Id"), Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.toList(),
                maps -> (Map<String, Object>) maps.stream()
                        .reduce(new HashMap<>(), (result, map) -> {
                            final List<Object> numbers = (List<Object>) result.getOrDefault("number", new ArrayList<>());

                            result.put("Id", map.getOrDefault("Id", result.getOrDefault("Id", null)));
                            result.put("location", map.getOrDefault("location", result.getOrDefault("location", null)));

                            if (map.containsKey("number")) {
                                numbers.add(map.get("number"));
                            }
                            result.put("number", numbers);

                            return result;
                        }))
                )
        )
        .values();

System.out.println(finalMaps);
```

In the first step you group all maps with the same `Id` value to a `List<Map<String,Object>>` (this is what `Collectors.toList()` passed to `.collectingAndThen()` does). After creating that list "finisher" function is called - in this case we transform list of maps into a single map using `Stream.reduce()` operation - we start with an empty `HashMap<String,Object>` and we iterate over maps, take values from current map in iteration and we set values according to your specification ("Id" and "location" gets overridden, "number" keeps a list of values).

#### Output

```
[{number=[123, 456], location=ny, Id=1}, {number=[789], location=ny, Id=2}]
```

To make code more simple you can extract `BiOperator` passed to `Stream.reduce` to a method and use method reference instead. This function defines what does it mean to combine two maps into single one, so it is the core logic of the whole reduction.

Comment: Hey @Szymon...Big thanks for taking the time to help me. The code works great!. Time to knuckle down and understand it a bit more :) you've gave me some direction, now its time to create that BiFunction +1

Comment: @rogger2016 Consider even extracting a class `Product` instead of a map, so you can end up with `Collection<Product>`. Then you could encapsulate merging two products in method like `Product merge(Product other)` and make the whole stream part even much simpler. Good luck! I'm glad I could help you

Comment: Could you shed some light on what (a, b) -> a) references?

Comment: @rogger2016 It was a combiner function that takes two maps, but in your case it is not used, so `(a,b) -> a` was always returned an accumulated map. I've updated code sample to use `Stream.reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)` which is all you need. It produces same result, less code. And in this case accumulator is expressed as `BiOperator` and not `BiFunction` since it requires two paramters with the same type and returns an object of the same as parameters type.